# How can you isolate the date portion of each request of a IP adress?

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python, counting, file

How can you isolate the date portion of each request of a IP address if it's at the first line of each request from a log file using awk, creating a list of distinct dates, and then using grep to create a list of requests for each date?

I thought maybe this first:

```
awk '$1=='$Current_date' {count++} END { print count}' weblog1.txt
```

to go through each date and count the adress

Comment: This site is for questions about Vim. For `awk` and `grep` try "Unix & Linux" SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about Vi or Vim.

Comment: Agree...off topic. But this may help. If you had a (space-separated in this case) file with dates in first column this will print a sorted list of unique dates and their counts: `awk '{ counts[$1]++ } END {for (date in counts) print date ":", counts[date] | "sort"}'  filename`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I also asked the mods for a migration to the U&L.